# Надо из метода вернуть значение или в противном случае null

Tags: java, массивы, методы

Есть метод и он должен возвращать null если размер массива не позволяет больше добавить в него новый элемент, то есть массив заполнен, а если позволяет, то возвращает какой-то параметр.

```
private User[] users = new User[10];
User user = new User(2453, "Ivan", "session");

public User save(User user){
    for (int i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
        if (user == findById(i)){          // добавляю в базу (массив) 
                                           // нового пользователя
            users[i] = null;
        }
        else users[i] = user;
    }
    if (User[users.length] )            // запись тут не правильная, но вот 
                                        // здесь и ступор у меня
}
```

Подскажите, как правильно мне это сделать ?

Comment: Проходите в цикле по массиву, если встретили null, тут же возвращайте параметр. После цикла возвращайте null.

Comment: может я не точно условие тут написал. Вот полная задача того, что надо мне сделать в методе: User save(User user) - который будет добавлять юзера в условную базу данных (массив)
и возвращать его, если юзер уже есть в массиве, результат - null. Если размер массива не позволяет добавить больше элементов. Результат метода тоже null

Comment: Дополняйте ваш вопрос согласно [рекомендациям по ведению дискуссий на Stack Overflow](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/691/6), вместо публикации комментариев.

Comment: база обязательно должна быть массивом? может ли быть использована коллекция (список)?

Comment: В том то и дело, что должна быть массивом. Коллекция не имеет определённого размера, в неё можно добавлять элементы, а тут условие именно такое.

Comment: Так как размер массива изначально задан как 10, то странное условие if (User[users.length] ) будет всегда выполняться. Проще всего окружить оператор "for" try catch:
try{
    for....
        }catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            return null;
        }

Comment: Я только в начале пути изучения языка программирования и поэтому в решениях задач пользуюсь только теми знаниями, которые получил на лекции, скажем так. Но всё равно, спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно пройтись по массиву и если нет null, нет места для новой записи, тогда выполнить условие вернуть null(проблема только в том, что null может быть на любом индексе и это работает для последовательного заполнения массива без удаления записей)

```
private User[] users = new User[10];
    User user = new User(2453, "Ivan", "session");
    public User save(User user){
        for(User usr: users) if(usr != null) return null;
        for (int i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
            if (user == findById(i)) {
                users[i] = null;
            }
            else users[i] = user;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Спасибо, Ваш ответ частично помог в решении данной задачи.

Answer (score 1):

```
private User[] users = new User[10];
User user = new User(2453, "Ivan", "session");
int first_empty;

public int save(User user){

    for (int i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
          if (!users[i].not_null){ //каким либо образом проверить
                                  //есть ли в элементе обьект 
        first_empty=i;
return first empty;
            //если есть место вернет номер (и прервет исполнение)
        }
//если полон возвратит ноль
    return null;       
        }
```

Даное решение не следит за количеством мест, но наличие оных точно говорит что масив не полон.

Comment: Исключения мы ещё не проходим ))) Мне надо без них сделать метод.